# nginx reverse proxy to a set of pages with an additional path in the URL based on http referer?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have a 3rd-party ui server running in a docker container, exposed on port 8080.

It seems to expect to load resources with an absolute path: `http://localhost:8080/index.html`, `http://localhost:8080/js/some_jsfiles`
etc.

I want to create a reverse proxy to it so it looks like it is coming from a different path:

`https://myserver.com/stormui/index.html`, `https://myserver.com/stormui/js/...`

first I tried

```
location /stormui/  {
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         #rewrite ^/stormui/(.*) /$1  break;
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
}
```

The index.html page loads, but the browser still tries to load the refered content without the additional path, so I get a 404 on all the javascripts etc referenced from index.html.

Then I tried to use referer to do the rewrite
    location / {

```
    if ($http_referer ~ "^/stormui/.*") {
        rewrite ^/(.*) /stormui/$1  break;
    }

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    ...
}
```

That didn't work, either.   Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does the generated index.html contain absolute URLs to the js/css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having similar issues while setting up nginx reverse proxy for **Storm-UI**

After digging for sometime, I got it working.

```
server {
    listen  80;

    server_name  example.com;

    location ^~ /css/ {
        rewrite /(.*) /storm-ui/$1;
    }

    location ^~ /js/ {
        rewrite /(.*) /storm-ui/$1;
    }

    location ^~ /templates/ {
            rewrite /(.*) /storm-ui/$1;
    }

    location ^~ /api/ {
            rewrite /(.*) /storm-ui/$1;
    }

    location ~ ^/topology(.*) {
            rewrite /(.*) /storm-ui/$1;
    }

    location  /storm-ui/ {
        proxy_redirect  /  /storm-ui/;
        #proxy_pass  http://<STORM_MASTER_IP/HOSTNAME>:<PORT>/;
        proxy_pass  http://10.14.23.10:8080/;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I fully understand. Does the HTML (e.g. index.html) from the UI server (running on localhost:8080) contain absolute URLs? If so, you have two options:

1. Rewrite the HTML in the proxy server. I.e. change the URLs according to your needs.
2. I'd imagine there must be some settings to configure your UI server (origin server) such that it doesn't use these absolute URLs to localhost:8080.

I can't answer #2 without more details on what is running on the backend.

Comment: The UI is the UI for Apache storm, running in docker.   I dug into their source code and indeed it looks like resources referenced from their index.html /all /have /absolute /paths.   Pretty crumby.    I guess my only option is to get the html rewrite pluging for nginx.

Comment: You should work / convince the Apache Storm community to fix their code. Not allowing for modifying the "base" of the URLs is crummy indeed. Ideally, they would use relative URLs when possible.

In fact, not being able to modify the base URLs makes it difficult, if not impossible, to put some of these resources behind a CDN style service provider.

Comment: Also, even if they are absolute (but without the http://), you might be able to add appropriate location / proxy_pass rules to nginx.