# nginx reverse proxy to a set of dockerized applications

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a linux server running a number of applications in docker containers running on the same machine, each exposed on its own port.
I'd like to be able to setup an nginx proxy through

```
http://myserver.example.com/firstapp/...
http://myserver.example.com/secondapp/...
http://myserver.example.com/thirdapp/...
etc.
```

I've setup the nginx `proxy.conf` (see below) so that when it gets an url `http://myserver.example.com/firstapp/<path>` rewrites it as `http://<firstapp container>:<port>/<path>`

The problem is that the HTML returned by the first URL of course includes links to files which do not contain the prefix `/firstapp/` so that I get for example:

```
http://myserver.example.com/css/myfile.css 404 Not Found
```

The solution in
[nginx reverse proxy to a set of pages with an additional path in the URL based on http referer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104003/nginx-reverse-proxy-to-a-set-of-pages-with-an-additional-path-in-the-url-based-o)
works only if I have a single application ("stormui"), but is not applicable when I have several dockerized applications running on the same server

I launch everything with a docker-compose.yml file like the following

```
version: '3.2'

services:

  proxy:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: proxy
    depends_on:
      - firstapp
      - secondapp
      - ...
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./proxy.conf
        target: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always


  firstapp:
    image: srv_firstapp:
    expose:
      - "8000"
    .
    .
    -

  secondapp:
    image: srv_firstapp:
    expose:
      - "8001"
    .
    .
    .
```

Mi attempt to write a nginx's proxy.conf file contains the following:

```
    .
    .
    .
    server {

     listen 80;
     server_name myserver.example.com;

     location /firstapp {
       proxy_pass http://firstapp:8000;
       rewrite ^/firstapp(.*)/firstapp$ $1 break;
     }

     location /secondapp {
       .
       .
       .
     }
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

Is there a way to solve this problem only through configuration of the nginx reverse proxy? (that is, without having to change the code or configuration of the various dockerized apps, to which I have no access)?

Comment: Interesting problem. Maybe your best bet here is to use the `$http_referer` inside your .conf file and try to create the necessary conditions based on this.

Comment: could you provide some additional detail? please take into account that I'm not an expert in nginx configuration (the .conf file I used was just copied from an example). thanks

Comment: Well I though that by using the `$http_referer` you could be able to apply some conditions but I think you can't achieve what I had in mind. I 'll try to come back with a detailed solution

Comment: I found a partial answer in this article:
http://sawers.com/blog/reverse-proxying-with-nginx/
that approaches the problem using the sub_filter directive. Quoting the article "It could involve days of trial and error. You'll definitely need your browser's developer tools view. You'll become intimately familiar with the internals of the application ... ". Actually I managed to rewrite some of the links generated in the html, but not everything works yet (ie. css and image files not found). Still have to work at it.